# Angular 2 - Passing param to custom validator

Tags: angular

I have my validator declared in the form builder:

```
            import { CustomValidators } from '../../custom-form-validators';

            export class SelectTicketsComponent implements OnInit {
            maxNumber: number = 20;

    this.myForm = this.fBuilder.group({
            fixtureName: 'Name',
            totalTicketsSelected: [this.calculateTotalTicketsSelectedPerMatch(10), Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
            CustomValidators.checkNumbers.bind(this.maxNumber)])]

    });
}
```

But I'm confused how I can get "maxNumber" variable over to the validator to check it?

```
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

// create your class that extends the angular validator class
export class CustomValidators extends Validators {

    // create a static method for your validation
    checkNumbers(control: FormControl): any {

        /* I want to compare control.value to maxNumber here */




    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have the `maxNumber` set in your validator, or alternatively move the validator to your component, where you have access to your `maxNumber` variable.

Comment: Please can you show me an example as to how to set maxNumber in the validator?

Comment: Well what I mean, is that you have to have the max number declared in the validator instead of component, but this does of course not work, if the max number is dynamic. It only works if the number is always 20.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn how to create a custom validators is to check how Google did this. Let’s look at [official validators](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/validators.ts)

As you can see, you need to return a function:

```
  static min(min: number): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  if (isEmptyInputValue(control.value) || isEmptyInputValue(min)) {
    return null;  // don't validate empty values to allow optional controls
  }
  const value = parseFloat(control.value);
  // Controls with NaN values after parsing should be treated as not having a
  // minimum, per the HTML forms spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-min
  return !isNaN(value) && value < min ? {'min': {'min': min, 'actual': control.value}} : null;
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although it is very old question i must post the answer here (hope it will  help somebody like me...)
The way to pass param to validator i found - is by using "bind" operator:

```
function CheckIfExistValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
  // "movies" is something we passing
  if (this.movies && this.movies.find(({title}) => title === control.value)) {        
    return { isExist: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

And in the code of component you can write something like:

```
 this.newMovie = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: ['', [Validators.required, CheckIfExistValidator.bind(this)]],
 })
```